# makeHttpRequest crashes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to retrieve data from an sql server, the gateway to the databench is an php script. That's fine.

I created a class ListView, as soon as an item is selected a new activity is startet. When this activity is started, an http get request is done:

Activity1 calls Activity2 ("EditItemActivity") when object is selected

```
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) 
            {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();
                String catID = prodCatCrossList.get(pid);

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditItemActivity.class);
                // sending parameters to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CATID, catID);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
```

The transfered parameters are fine I double checked this.

Now the Activity2.oncreate is called:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_item);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);
    catID = i.getStringExtra(TAG_CATID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

}
```

And finally the async task which crashes:   class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask 
    {

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
    {
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {

                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_item_details, "GET", params);
                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                            //...........
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                        
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }
```

The params values are correct, the syntax within the json stream is also right.

I'm quiet sure that "makeHttpRequest" causes the errors, but I don't see why? In activity1 I already retrieved successfully data from my server...

Who can help?

The following error messages are created:

```
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at com.dafocus.shoporganizer.JSonParser.makeHttpRequest(JSonParser.java:63)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at com.dafocus.shoporganizer.EditItemActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(EditItemActivity.java:136)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
11-02 16:27:12.053: E/AndroidRuntime(17563):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-02 16:27:52.873: D/dalvikvm(17563): GC_CONCURRENT freed 142K, 13% free 10241K/11719K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 16ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove runOnUiThread in `doInbackground`. You are executing your network related operation inside `runOnUiThread` ( on the ui thread).

You need to run network related operation in `doInbackground` which is invoked on the background thread

Answer (score 0):

Like @Raghunandan said you're explicitly doing network job on the main thread. Dalvik virtual machine which is responsible for handling all the Android applications doesn't allow that. That's why your application crashes once it issues a network (in this case JSON) request on its main thread.